# Splitting a string and putting it back together

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have a string which is in a format like "C 01 ABC 02 AB"

I'm splitting it with

```
string[] line = String.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and it works like a charm.

But I need to put it back in a different format.

I need first C then "01 ABC 02" and then lastly AB separately.

Basically I need to change "C 01 ABC 02 AB" into three smaller strings as "C" "01 ABC 02" and "AB".

Sadly , ABC and 02 parts can change in length to I can't assign a fixed variable to do the split.

I tried string.Join but didn't work as I wanted it to.

Seems like all other examples are joining whole array into a single string, how can I do this?

Comment: Can´t you just do something like `str1=line[0];str2=line[1]+line[2]+line[3];str3=line[4];` or there is something i don't understand in your question?

Comment: is C and AB of fixed length?

Comment: There are a few possibilities, but you haven't made clear what defines these "parts".  How will you know what to separate first, what is second, etc.?  Are the spaces the defining attributes of the incoming string?  Otherwise, it just looks like random groupings...

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. Only fail-safe way of splitting is using spaces. C and AB are fixed in length. ABC and 02 can differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is always build that first and last string parts ("C" and "AB") are without spaces, you can use something like this:

```
string[] parts = "C 01 ABC 02 AB".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string part1 = parts[0]; // "C"
string part2 = string.Join(" ", parts.Skip(1).Take(parts.Length - 2)); // "01 ABC 02"
string part3 = parts[parts.Length - 1]; // "AB"
```

If it's always fixed 5 parts you can simplify this:

```
string[] parts = "C 01 ABC 02 AB".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string part1 = parts[0]; // "C"
string part2 = string.Join(" ", parts.Skip(1).Take(3)); // "01 ABC 02"
string part3 = parts[4]; // "AB"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you right, you want

```
 "C 01 ABC 02 AB" ->             ["C", "01 ABC 02", "AB"]             // 3 items
 "C 01 ABC 02 bla bla bla AB" -> ["C", "01 ABC 02 bla bla bla", "AB"] // 3 items
 "C 01 02 AB"     ->             ["C", "01 02", "AB"]                 // 3 items
```

in that case

```
  String source = "C 01 ABC 02 AB";

  int first = source.IndexOf(' ');
  int last = source.LastIndexOf(' '); 

  String[] line = new String[] {
    source.Substring(0, first),
    source.Substring(first + 1, last - first - 1),
    source.Substring(last + 1),
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how varying the input data is you could also use a regular expression like `^(.+)\s(\d+\s.+?\s\d+)\s(.+)`. This will result in a match with three groups containing the seperate pieces "C" "01 ABC 02" and "AB".

This does mean that the middle part must always exist of digits followed by a string and then followed by digits again. Added advantage is that you also check that the input string is of a certain format.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = Regex.Match("C 01 ABC 02 AB", @"^(.+)\s(\d+\s.+?\s\d+)\s(.+)");
        Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[0].Value); // "C 01 ABC 02 AB"
        Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1].Value); // "C"
        Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[2].Value); // "01 ABC 02"
        Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[3].Value); // "AB"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
string x = "C 01 ABC 02 AB";
string s1 = x.Substring(0, 1);
string s2 = x.Substring(2, x.Length - 5);
string s3 = x.Substring(x.Length - 2);
```

Considering C and AB's length will never change.

Comment: looks nice but sadly using var types are frowned upon in our company :)

Comment: Got it so changed it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to extract your values:

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"(?<first>[A-Z0-9]+)\s(?<second>(([0-9]+)\s([A-Z]+)\s[0-9]+))\s(?<third>[A-Z]+)");
var line = pattern.Match(input);
var first = line.Groups["first"].Value;
var second = line.Groups["second"].Value;
var third = line.Groups["third"].Value;
```

Or you could substring the chunks:

```
var first = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
var second = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1, line.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
var third = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Or use Linq to select the different chunks:

```
string[] line = String.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var first = line.First();
var second = string.Join(' ', line.Skip(1).Take(3).ToArray());
var third = line.Last();
```